# How to read from AIR manifest file within AS / MXML code

Tags: apache-flex, air, manifest

Flash Builder generated AppName-app.xml descriptor for every AIR project. There are a number of settings, values there, including below. Is it possible to read these in your code without explicitly loading this XML at runtime (even this I don't know if it's possible)? Maybe Loader.info or similar?

```
<!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. 
         May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <name>ffff</name>

    <!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. 
    Values can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value.
    An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
    <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>


    <!-- Description, displayed in the AIR application installer.
         May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <!-- <description></description> -->

    <!-- Copyright information. Optional -->
    <!-- <copyright></copyright> -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to read is called the "Application Descriptor".

It is XML, but it is very easy read:

```
var appXml:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;

namespace ns = "http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5";
use namespace ns;

Alert.show("appId: " + appXml.id);
Alert.show("version: " + appXml.versionNumber);
Alert.show("filename: " + appXml.filename);
```

Notice that I set the namespace to the one I am using.  You should make sure you use the namespace defined in the root of your application descriptor.

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the tip on namespace, I'de have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do as follows :

```
var appXml:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
var ns:Namespace = appXml.namespace();
title = appXml.ns::name + " " + appXml.ns::versionNumber;
```

Thus you don't need to hardcode the namespace in your code.